# use awk variable in bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have a txt file with blow format:

```
66.57.21 - john
88.43.23 - albert
10.10.11 - smith
```

I wanna to execute "connect.py 66.57.21 john" for each line and I wrote this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read LINE; do
awk -v number = "$LINE" '$1'
awk -v name = "$LINE" '$3'
  connect.py $name $number
done < "$1"
```

but the bash script didn't work

What is the problem

Comment: Why not `while read -r ip stuff user; do connect.py "$ip" john; done < file.txt`? By reading into 3 variables, the `read` will separate the information for you.

Comment: See [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) And that use of `awk` is pretty completely wrong.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with your scripting.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read -r number _ name; do
  connect.py "$name" "$number"
done < "$1"
```

Comment: Hey! `connect.py "$name" "$number" < /dev/tty` might be safer in case connect.py would read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to use awk, here is one way to do it:

```
awk -F" " '{system("connect.py " $3 " " $1)}' input.txt
```

The `-F" "` splits each line of input on spaces

`$1` is the first word in the array (number in the original question)

`$3` is he third word in the array (name in the original question)

wrapping `"connect.py " $3 " " $1` in `system()` causes the shell to execute the command after the substitutions have been made

ie: `connect.py john 66.57.21`

Comment: One thing you want to avoid in scripting is spawning subshells within a loop. That makes shell scripts S L O W.... Here you are spawning 9 subshells every iteration. Command substitution spawns a subshell. Each pipe takes a subshell and you have commands on either side of the pipe. Ouch! If you are reading 1000 or so lines, no problem, if it is 1,000,000 - go get lunch and check back much later. Always try and limit or eliminate this type behavior. Here, if you want to use `awk`, you can do the entire thing in a single call to `awk` and use `system()` for the connection. Advice -- no dings.

Comment: Also, you are commiting a *UUOc* (*Unnecessary Use of `cat`*, also stated as *Useless Use of `cat`*). Whenever you do `cat file ...` and are not concatenating files, it is a *UUOc*. Usually seen as `cat file | someUtility`. See [Useless Use of Cat](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html). Instead all utilities will either take the filenames as an argument or take input on `stdin`. So it is properly `someUtility file` or `someUtility < file`. ... `:)`

Comment: You also have unquoted variables, are using `read` in a way it'll corrupt lines containing escapes, using all upper case variable names inappropriately, etc. Copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues.

Comment: Thank you both. I have updated based on your collective feedback. Let me know what you think.